# How do I pull indexed information from a table collected with bs4? (Python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape legislation information from [nysenate.gov](https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/bills/2019/s5918). I'm using bs4 and Python in a Jupyter Notebook. There's a table that may/may not contain the following information:

1. A bill delivered to the governor (and date)
2. Bill sign by gov (and date)
3. Bill vetoed by gov (and date)

I'm able to collect #1 without issue. But numbers 2 & 3 keep falling apart. I suspect it's because there's extra, auto-generated text specific to the bill that keeps blowing up my scraper. I tried using regex to get around that. Here's what I've tried:

```
    tablebody=soup.select_one(".table.c-bill--actions-table > tbody")
                
    check_list = [item.text.strip() for item in tablebody.select("td")]
    
    #print(check_list)

    if "delivered to governor" in check_list:
        transfer_list.append("delivered to governor")
        i = check_list.index("delivered to governor")
        transfer_list.append(check_list[i+1])

    else:
        transfer_list.append("not delivered")
        transfer_list.append("no date")

    if regex_for_signed in check_list:
        transfer_list.append("signed")
        i = check_list.index("signed")
        transfer_list.append(check_list[i+1])

    else:
        transfer_list.append("not signed")
        transfer_list.append("no date")

    if regex_for_vetoed in check_list or "tabledvetoed" in check_list:
        transfer_list.append("vetoed")
        i = check_list.index("vetoed")
        transfer_list.append(check_list[i+1])

    else:
        transfer_list.append("not vetoed")
        transfer_list.append("no date")
```

Here's the regex I'm using:

```
regex_for_signed = r"((?i)signed).*"
regex_for_vetoed = r"((?i)vetoed).*"
```

And here are the two webpages I'm using to test my code:

https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/bills/2019/s5903 (Signed)
https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/bills/2019/s5918 (Vetoed)

I'm trying to `output` this to a CSV file. For the `signed` and `vetoed` scenarios, it always uses the `else` statements - even when it shouldn't.

Comment: `regex_for_signed in check_list` is not doing a regular expression search (adding `r` is to make it a raw string), just a simple exact text search over your list. You would need `re.search()`

Comment: What is your desired CSV output format? Please add it to the question

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible approach for writing your results to a CSV file for multiple URLS:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

urls = [
    "https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/bills/2019/s5903",
    'https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/bills/2019/s5918',
]

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['Date', 'Status', 'Text'])
    
    for url in urls:
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        table_body = soup.select_one(".table.c-bill--actions-table > tbody")

        for tr in table_body.find_all('tr'):
            entry_date, entry_text = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.find_all('td')]
            status = ""
        
            if "delivered to governor" in entry_text:
                status = "delivered to governor"
            elif "signed" in entry_text:
                status = "signed"
            
            csv_output.writerow([entry_date, status, entry_text])
```

For regular expressions, you will need to use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.search)